# Excel Rule or Formula If greater than or equal to but not greater than value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry if my title made no sense. but this is what I'm trying to get to work .

```
A1     B1
10     10.4
```

if B1 is equal to A1 or 10+10% but not greater than A1+11% change cell to green.

I'm fairly new to excel but i was able to come up with =IF(AND(B1<=A1+10%),B1=A1). I don't have a clue were i can add "but not greater than "A1+11%". maybe I'm doing it all wrong. Some guidance would be amazing. Thanks!

UPDATE 1:
I have `=IF( C3=A3,C3=A3*1.1,NOT(C3>=A3*1.11))` Currently and it works but not when C3 is equal to A3. It doesnt change color to yellow

Comment: You can use conditional format formula =B1<=A1*1.10

Comment: but not greater than A1+11% can be written as less than or equal to A1*1.11. So you can simply put and ```AND(B1=A1, B1=A1*1.1, B1<=A1*1.11)```. Hope that helps.

Comment: it wouldnt require to put it inside an IF()? just AND(B1=A1, B1=A1*1.1, B1<=A1*1.11)  ?

Comment: @gouravkr  If third condition B1<=A1*1.11 is checked then its sufficient. It automatically accepts the first two conditions as true Hence, only once formula =B1<=A1*1.11 is ok

Comment: @MiguelAngelQuintana this is the condition block, if you are using it to calculate value, put it as the first argument of =IF(). If you are using it for conditional formatting, then you don't need to put =IF()

Comment: @Naresh you are right. The question is not entirely clear. I just wanted to point to the alternate representation of not greater than.